# Does voltage in my PC's case indicate a circuit grounding problem?

Tags: electrical

Today I was on my computer, and I wanted to plug in an external battery powered speaker to my PC's front audio jack using an AUX cable.

I noticed as soon as I plugged it in the familiar burning smell when something like a capacitor or resistor burns out, so I immediately unplugged everything and noticed that the AUX cable was very hot. After I had a poke around inside my computer, I couldn't really see anything that looked damaged. After I had a go turning it on again, the audio still worked (through the rear jack) so it looks like it didn't blow the sound part of my motherboard.

However, after doing some more investigating, I noticed I could feel a slight tingle on my computer case when touching the case and what I think is a grounded point in my house (touching the shielding of a coax cable coming out of my wall). After making sure my PC was plugged into a grounded socket, I still felt this sensation. Even weirder, when I unplugged the case, I still felt the sensation when touching the grounded point.

Could this mean there is something wrong with my ground and it always has some potential running through it?

Comment: Do you have a volt meter?  Can you check the voltage from an unpainted part of the computer to the ground hole of the outlet?  The speakers wouldn't be grounded anyway, so not sure how that plays into this.

Comment: Shielding of a coax. cable is **not** necessarily "ground of the house". Logically it should be. But logic doesn't always work when cable companies are involved. The real test is to the ground of an *electric outlet* - but better with a multimeter than your finger.

Comment: When it went wrong, what was connected to the battery powered speaker? Only the audio cable, or was it also plugged to its own charger? If the speaker was plugged into its charger, the charger could be the culprit.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'm going to the shops tomorrow to pick up a multimeter and a socket tester.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Reinstate Monica I'll try measuring it with a multimeter next.

Comment: @peufeu It was only the audio cable, that's what led me to believe it was something with the computer itself being live, so the grounding of the case was connected to the grounding of the AUX cable.

Comment: It might be worth borrowing a voltmeter instead of risking your life using yourself as one.  Electricity is fickle (or to be more precise, conductivity of things *not made* to be conductors or insulators is highly variant).

Comment: If the AUX cable was hot it means high current ran through it. However current flows in a loop. If the speaker was not connected to anything except the PC then what is the loop ? AUX jacks aren't supposed to be connected to circuits capable of high-current... Another hypothesis... Is the speaker's enclosure made of metal, and did it make contact with the PC ground?

Comment: @peufeu The speaker is not made of metal, and is not connected to the ground. My hypothesis is that the case itself is under power, so anything grounded to the case is also under power. This means the ground of the AUX cable is also under power, then the power ending up having a place to go, the speaker.

Comment: If the case is under power, for example case shorted to mains, that would be dangerous. You can test this with a multimeter, measure voltage between PC case and Earth, take precautions. But it wouldn't fry your audio cable... the cable connects the speaker's ground to the PC ground, so they will be at the same potential, but that doesn't mean current will flow in the cable. Where would the current go? It needs a loop, and I wonder what it is...

Comment: @pefeu Yeah it's really strange. I'll get the multimeter tomorrow to measure it, and I'll report back here what I've found.

Comment: was your "battery powered speaker" connected to anything other than the computer?

Comment: I suspect that you may have connected the front audio jack to the wrong place inside the PC, perhaps to a USB or firewire  header.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with your theory that the case is under power.  This may be due to a **ground fault** in the PC's power supply.  It could also be some other appliance raising ground due to *its* ground fault combining with a gap in the grounding system.

It's possible to have "islanded grounds" where a bunch of equipment grounds connect to each other, but do not connect to the actual earth. In an islanded-ground situation, you have the lowest common denominator; a ground fault on any of them lights up all of them.

The Equipment Safety Grounding System (outlet to panel), combined with the Grounding Electrode System (panel to ground rods), should be handling that properly.  I'd say it's time to give both systems a heavy inspection with a 10 foot pole... sorry, I mean *with a fine-tooth comb*.

If your grounding electrode system is faulty, that's where the 10-foot poles come in.